# Vagrant on windows - git protocol error

Tags: windows, git, vagrant

I have a vagrant machine set up with shared folders on windows to code my project.
I use git and sometimes when I do git checkout or git merge I get the following error:

```
error: unable to create file XXXXX: Protocol error
```

Then the git process doesn't complete and leaves me with uncommited changes which shouldn't actually exist.
I tried to look up this error all over, and had no luck finding an answer for this.
Closest thing I could find was in this thread:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43763026/unable-to-create-drivers-xxx-xxx-xxx-c-protocol-error

Which doesn't really answer the question.